# hiding elements using jquery button click

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I have four buttons and I want to show/hide elements on click.

```
 <input name="0rope" class= "css3button 0rope"type="button" value="0"  />
 <input name="1rope" class= "css3button 1rope"type="button" value="1"  />
 <input name="2rope" class= "css3button 2rope"type="button" value="2"  />
 <input name="3rope" class= "css3button 3rope"type="button" value="3"  />
```

I tried this code, but its not working, can you help

```
 $(".input.css3button.0rope").click(function(){
    $("#img3,#img4,#img5,.4,.5,.6,.4b,.5b,.6b").hide();
  });
   $(".input.css3button.1rope").click(function(){
    $("#img3,#img4,.4,.5,.4b,.5b").hide();
    $("#img5,.6,.6b").show();
  });
     $(".input.css3button.2rope").click(function(){
    $("#img3,.4,.4b").hide();
    $("#img4,#img5,.5,.5b,.6,.6b").show();
      });
      $(".input.css3button.3rope").click(function(){
    $("#img3,#img4,#img5,.4,.5,.6,.4b,.5b,.6b").show();
  });
```

Comment: post your full html and explain more about what you want..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few formatting issues with your HTML, as well as an issue with the class names you're using. You need to add a space before `type="button"`, and also class names starting with  numbers cause issues with CSS selectors—they must start with letters (a-z), an underscore, or a hyphen in order to use the standard `.classname` or `#classname` selectors in your CSS files ([see here](http://benfrain.com/when-and-where-you-can-use-numbers-in-id-and-class-names/)), so I'd recommend changing 0rope to rope0, etc:

```
<input name="rope0" class="css3button rope0" type="button" value="0" />
<input name="rope1" class="css3button rope1" type="button" value="1" />
<input name="rope2" class="css3button rope2" type="button" value="2" />
<input name="rope3" class="css3button rope3" type="button" value="3" />
```

Also, in your jQuery selectors (the code inside the `$('')` call), you have `.input` at the beginning of the selector. This will make jQuery look for elements with an `input` class on them, eg `class="css3button rope0 input"`. To make it look for `<input>` elements, simply remove the leading `.`:

```
$("input.css3button.rope0").click(function(){
```

Comment: Indeed, but it still causes issues elsewhere. I'd still recommend sticking to the old rules. See: http://benfrain.com/when-and-where-you-can-use-numbers-in-id-and-class-names/

Comment: Wording changed, then. :p

Comment: thank you for your comments, I have done everything you suggested and it works absolutely perfectly, thank you so much